# What is the $/K on the stats screen?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I'm wondering what the $/K stat on the score screen is.

What does it mean? How is it calculated?

Comment: Just a guess, $/K = dollars per kill? Tell me I am right!

Comment: Would be my guess too, but just to be sure. Also, why would it be a relevant info to know?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The stat is based on how much money you've spent per kill.

For example, you buy a desert eagle in the pistol round for $800 and kill 2 enemies, your $/K stat will be $400.

The lower the number the better, it means you are more cost efficient as a player with the weapons/equipment that you buy.